# Printing acronyms not in italics

Tags: acronyms, acro

When defining an acronym, I define its long version in italics because I want it to be written out in italics in the actual text. However, when I print the acronyms in the acronyms table in the very beginning of the document, I want the long version to be non-italic. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{se}{short=SE,long=\emph{StackExchange}}

\begin{document}
    \printacronyms
    
    \ac{se}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) allows separate formatting to be applied to the long and list form through the `long-format` and `list-format` keys. This allows entirely acronym-specific settings and does not require any redefinitions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{se}{
  short=SE,
  long=StackExchange,
  long-format=\emph,
  list-format=,
}

\begin{document}
  \printacronyms
  \ac{se}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`list-format` by default takes the `long-format` style, so after setting `long-format` we need to reset `list-format` to be empty.

Comment: I'll ask the OP to accept your answer. I was reading the `acronym` documentation not the `acro` documentation.

Comment: Fair enough... :)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this is to create a command for the long form introduction and then redefine it locally for the list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\newcommand\longfont[1]{\emph{#1}}
\DeclareAcronym{se}{short=SE,long=\longfont{StackExchange}}

\begin{document}
% We enclose the \printacronyms command and redefinition in
% a group { ... } so that the redefinition is local.
{\let\longfont\relax
    \printacronyms
}    
    \ac{se}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Wonderful. I definitely learnt something from this!

Comment: @Zuy You should un-accept my answer and accept the other answer. I was mistakenly using the `acronym` package documentation instead of the `acro` package.  So there's a more straightforward solution (although the general method here is certainly useful in other cases.)